# How to bring TableViewController to back

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, statusbar

I've a UITableViewController.

But when I'm scrolling to top, table data can be seeing on the status bar like this:

[image]

[image]

How can I bypass this moment?

Comment: try changing content offset to 20 from top

Comment: anyway when I'm scrolling I see data on the status bar

Comment: @HrenoHrenovich are you using navigation controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide status bar using next snippet:

```
override func prefersStatusBarHidden() -> Bool {
    return true;
}
```

Or you can set contentInsets

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(60, 0, 0, 0)
```

There possibly other solutions (like changing constraint of tableView) depends on your requirements